# How to traverse along contenteditable components with arrow keys in javascript (or jquery implementation)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-keys

I was working on my sub project to implement on the Notion like text editor. This text editor consists of multiple contenteditable instead of using a single contenteditable for entire text.

The problem I've faced is that I cannot go upward or downward with arrow keys unless I define the functions by listening to the arrow keys ( 37~ 40) and defining various cases to move upward or downward or move from the tip of the left side to upward or whatever.

Is this a nature of this so leaving the developers to handle all cases? or am I not aware of a simple way to implement this without struggling with defining all possible scenario?

Looking forward to seeing any great feedbacks!

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="selectable" data-indent='0'>
        <div 
        class="contenteditable" contenteditable="true" 
        data-indent='0'
        placeholder="Enter text here..."
        style="min-height:1em; 
        width:100%;
        padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px;
        border:0px solid gold;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="selectable" data-indent='0'>
        <div 
        class="contenteditable" contenteditable="true" 
        data-indent='0'
        placeholder="Enter text here..."
        style="min-height:1em; 
        width:100%;
        padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px;
        border:0px solid gold;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="selectable" data-indent='0'>
        <div 
        class="contenteditable" contenteditable="true" 
        data-indent='0'
        placeholder="Enter text here..."
        style="min-height:1em; 
        width:100%;
        padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px;
        border:0px solid gold;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the point of `border:0px solid gold;`? Maybe `tab` for down and `shift+tab` for up would be more intuitive? Does `placeholder="Enter text here..."` actually work on a non-form control such as a `<div>`? You should provide a [mcve] by clicking the bracket button `<>`

Comment: any luck with this? did you manage to build one or used any library?